# gevent, sockets and synchronisation

Tags: python, sockets, gevent

I have multiple greenlets sending on a common socket. Is it guaranteed that each package sent via `socket.sendall` is well separated or do I have to acquire a lock before each call to `sendall`.

So I want to prevent the following scenario:

- *g1* sends `ABCD`
- *g2* sends `1234`
- received data is mixed up, for example `AB1234CD`
- expected is either `ABCD1234` or `1234ABCD`

#### Update

After a look at the [sourcecode](https://github.com/SiteSupport/gevent/blob/master/gevent/socket.py#L284) I think this scenario cannot happen. But I have to use a lock because g1 or g2 can crash on the `sendall`. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Are you getting this king of output in present state?

Comment: Plz, place here example of your code. From where you send and for whom

Comment: @Denis I'm in the state of redesigning some asyncore code to gevent. So there isn't yet any code related to gevent. This is mostly a theoretical consideration. Anyway, the question should be clear...

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Nope, see comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some tests with a high latency / low bandwitch interface and got the expected error.

- Simulation of slow interface: https://superuser.com/a/147434
- Test script: https://gist.github.com/4249827/6779dfbebc255e81252e9b29c94add98c5771669

This resulted (as expected) in the following error:

```
AssertionError: This event is already used by another greenlet: (<Greenlet 
at 0x7f3e758722d0: <bound method socket.sendall of <socket at 0x7f3e7587719
0 fileno=8 sock=127.0.0.1:1234 peer=127.0.0.1:51042>>('11111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111)>, timeout('timed out',))
```

Here is the fixed test script with a `gevent.coros.RLock` which doesn't yield this error: https://gist.github.com/4249827/7f02f805331eda4091ae0b39dfea4b102cdba2fa